# How do I extract all human-readable strings from my Ruby/Rails project for spell and grammar checking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

In my RoR project I have human readable strings stored all over the place (e.g. HAML template, Javascript, Controller, Models, etc). Before I take the site public I'd like to extract all of these human readable strings out of my code for spell/grammar checking.

Are there any gems or rake jobs that will extract all of these human readable strings for review?

Comment: you mean tags, code and all stuff?? Why do want to do that?? For checking html tags there is XML schema others there are other tools

Comment: Human readable contents exists in many places in a RoR app. Obviously in your templates, but it's also in the JS for your app, controllers (sometimes they return errors with hard-coded strings), I've seen models that generate contents too. I just want to extract all of the contents and see a readout "[file] - [line number]: [string]". That way I can check the copy in one go as opposed to sifting through all the files.

Answer (score 0):

The gem most suitable for your needs may be [Copycopter](http://railscasts.com/episodes/336-copycopter).